# Opening some PDF files in Photoshop shows "Import PDF" prompt, some don't. Why?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, pdf, import, data-merge

I have just started using Data Sets and all of my interchangeable graphics were saved from Photoshop as Photoshop PDFs without layers.

Now I run the export data sets command and the process stops to prompt me for importing some of these PDF files (every time they change as well!). This meant I had to click <kbd>OK</kbd> approximately 1000 times during the export process, which is undesirable, but the output was fine.

When I try opening the PDFs directly in Photoshop, the behaviour is the same: some open the “Import PDF” prompt and some just load directly. I would like to know what triggers this prompt, so I can avoid it in future.

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately Photoshop remembers the import settings you select the first time the dialog pops up, so from then on you just need to press enter a few hundred/thousand times. I found a small weight and placed it on the enter key, so the process no longer requires manual oversight. This is a workaround rather than a solution, but it seems like the only way.